# Extjs: Disable Tab Key Navigation in a Form

Tags: extjs, combobox

I have an ExtJS Form with several form fields, few of them are ComboBoxes - with a special handler on Tab Key Press. 
While I am able to handle the Tab key press to show a popup with options for further filtering, The Tab key press also sets focus on the next form field. I want to know a way to disable focus change on Tab Key press in the form.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with negative tabIndex or you can set listener for focus and when tab index is pressed (you can use ASCII) to catch the key and based on it we can prevent being focused...if I understood your question proper. below is sample code for tab index

```
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'name',
    fieldLabel: 'Name',
    tabIndex: -1
```

Comment: lets says, I have a combobox, followed by a textfield. In combobox, I press Tab Key,I handle tab key press, but focus still changes to textfield. I want the focus to stay on the combobox itself. Does this clarify ?

Comment: If I understand what you mean, you have a function executed on focus on the textfield, and you want that it will be executed only when we click on textfield and not when we press tab key on the combobox?